# A Problem regarding loadExceptions and IllegalArguementException

Tags: java, exception, fxml, illegalargumentexception, javafx-11

Ok, so I designed two guis and also have 2 controllers for each of them. So basically the first window/gui (LoginMain.fxml) has a sign up button and when you click it, it opens the other gui (SignUP.fxml). But for some reason when I associate the SignUP.fxml file with its controller it doesn't open up when I click the sign up button. But when I don't associate it, it works fine.

Here's my main method:

```
package sample;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
    Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("LoginMain.fxml"));
    primaryStage.setTitle("Ford Car Review");
    primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 550, 450));
    primaryStage.show();
}


public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}
}
```

Here's my loginMain.fxml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.*?>
<AnchorPane prefHeight="426.0" prefWidth="547.0" style="-fx-background-color: #2D3447; 
-fx-border- color: yellow;"
        xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/10.0.2-internal" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1"
        fx:controller="sample.LoginController">
<TextField fx:id="username" layoutX="195.0" layoutY="155.0" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="197.0"
       promptText="Enter username" style="-fx-background-color: white;"><font>
       <Font size="14.0" />
       </font>
       </TextField>
       <PasswordField fx:id="password" layoutX="195.0" layoutY="200.0" 
       prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="197.0"
       promptText="Enter password" style="-fx-background-color: white;">
       <font>
       <Font size="14.0" />
       </font>
       </PasswordField>
       <Button fx:id="signUpButton" layoutX="446.0" layoutY="368.0" 
       onAction="#signUp"  prefHeight="30.0"
              prefWidth="70.0" text="Sign Up">
        <font>
           <Font size="14.0" />
        </font>
       </Button>
       <Button fx:id="login" layoutX="297.0" layoutY="267.0" onAction="#loginAction"
              prefHeight="30.0" prefWidth="61.0" text="Login" />
       <CheckBox fx:id="remember" layoutX="152.0" layoutY="267.0" prefHeight="30.0"
                prefWidth="107.0" text="Remember Me" textFill="WHITE" />
       <Button fx:id="forgotPassword" layoutX="167.0" layoutY="316.0" mnemonicParsing="false"
       prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="197.0" style="-fx-background-color: #2D3447;" 
       text="Forgot Your Password?"
       textFill="WHITE" underline="true" />
       <ImageView fitHeight="83.0" fitWidth="129.0" layoutX="152.0" 
        layoutY="23.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true">
       <image>
       <Image url="@../img/images.jpg" />
       </image>
       </ImageView>
       <ImageView fitHeight="30.0" fitWidth="35.0" layoutX="152.0" layoutY="155.0" 
       pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true">
       <image>
       <Image url="@../img/username.jpg" />
       </image>
       </ImageView>
       <ImageView fitHeight="30.0" fitWidth="30.0" layoutX="152.0" layoutY="200.0" 
       pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true">
       <image>
       <Image url="@../img/password.png" />
       </image>
       </ImageView>
       <Label layoutX="285.0" layoutY="23.0" prefHeight="30.0" prefWidth="84.0"
       text="FORD" textFill="#6958d7">
       <font>
       <Font name="Century Schoolbook" size="20.0" />
       </font>
       </Label>
       <Label layoutX="285.0" layoutY="53.0" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="70.0" 
       text="CAR"     textFill="#6958d7">
       <font>
       <Font name="Century Schoolbook" size="20.0" />
       </font>
       </Label>
       <Label layoutX="284.0" layoutY="81.0" text="REVIEW" textFill="#6958d7">
       <font>
       <Font name="Century Schoolbook" size="20.0" />
       </font>
       </Label>
       <ImageView fx:id="progress" fitHeight="83.0" fitWidth="125.0" layoutX="210.0" layoutY="341.0"
          pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true">
       <image>
       <Image url="@../img/source.gif" />
       </image>
       </ImageView>
       </AnchorPane>
```

Here's my Login Controller class:

```
package sample;

import javafx.animation.PauseTransition;
import javafx.fxml.FXML; 
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.CheckBox;
import javafx.scene.control.PasswordField;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Duration;
import java.io.IOException;

public class LoginController {

@FXML
private Button signUpButton;
@FXML
private TextField username;
@FXML
private CheckBox remember;
@FXML
private Button login;
@FXML
private Button forgotPassword;
@FXML
private ImageView progress;
@FXML
private PasswordField password;

public void initialize() {
    progress.setVisible(false);
}

@FXML
public void loginAction() {
    progress.setVisible(true);
    PauseTransition pt = new PauseTransition();
    pt.setDuration(Duration.seconds(3));
    pt.setOnFinished(e -> System.out.println("Login Successfully"));
    pt.play();
}

@FXML
public void signUp() {
    try {
        login.getScene().getWindow().hide();
        Stage signUpStage = new Stage();
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(Main.class.getResource("/sample/SignUP.fxml"));
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        signUpStage.setScene(scene);
        signUpStage.show();
        signUpStage.setResizable(false);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

Here's my SignUP.fxml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.*?>
<AnchorPane prefHeight="462.0" prefWidth="547.0" style="-fx-background-color: #2D3447; 
-fx-border-color: yellow;"
        xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/10.0.2-internal" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1"
        fx:controller="sample.SignUpController">
<TextField layoutX="160.0" layoutY="145.0" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="228.0" 
 promptText="Enter Username" style="-fx-background-color: white;">
<font>
<Font size="14.0" />
</font>
</TextField>
<PasswordField layoutX="160.0" layoutY="190.0" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="228.0" 
promptText="Enter Password" style="-fx-background-color: #2D34white47;">
<font>
<Font size="14.0" />
</font>
</PasswordField>
<RadioButton layoutX="168.0" layoutY="248.0" mnemonicParsing="false" selected="true" 
text="Male" textFill="#a0a2ab">
<font>
<Font size="14.0" />
</font>
<toggleGroup>
<ToggleGroup fx:id="gender" />
</toggleGroup>
</RadioButton>
<RadioButton layoutX="239.0" layoutY="248.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Female" 
textFill="#a0a2ab" toggleGroup="$gender">
<font>
<Font size="14.0" />
</font>
</RadioButton>
<TextField layoutX="160.0" layoutY="289.0" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="228.0" 
promptText="Enter Location">
<font>
<Font size="14.0" />
</font>
</TextField>
<Button layoutX="136.0" layoutY="350.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="30.0" prefWidth="239.0"
onAction="#signUP" style="-fx-background-color: #2196f3;" text="Sign UP" textFill="#ddd1d1">
<font>
<Font size="14.0" />
</font>
</Button>
<ImageView fitHeight="30.0" fitWidth="33.0" layoutX="121.0" layoutY="243.0"
pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true">
<image>
<Image url="@../img/gender.png" />
</image>
</ImageView>
<ImageView fitHeight="30.0" fitWidth="30.0" layoutX="121.0" layoutY="145.0" 
pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true">
<image>
<Image url="@../img/username.jpg" />
</image>
</ImageView>
<ImageView fitHeight="30.0" fitWidth="30.0" layoutX="121.0" layoutY="190.0" 
pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true">
<image>
<Image url="@../img/password.png" />
</image>
</ImageView>
<ImageView fitHeight="30.0" fitWidth="30.0" layoutX="121.0" layoutY="289.0"
pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true">
<image>
<Image url="@../img/location.png" />
</image>
</ImageView>
<Button layoutX="448.0" layoutY="36.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="30.0" 
 prefWidth="56.0" style="-fx-background-color: #2196f3;" text="Login" textFill="WHITE" />
<ImageView fitHeight="89.0" fitWidth="131.0" layoutX="121.0" layoutY="14.0"
pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true">
<image>
<Image url="@../img/images.jpg" />
</image>
</ImageView>
<Label layoutX="260.0" layoutY="14.0" prefHeight="30.0" prefWidth="84.0" 
text="FORD" textFill="#7a6ae4">
<font>
<Font name="Century Schoolbook" size="20.0" />
</font>
</Label>
<Label layoutX="260.0" layoutY="43.0" prefHeight="30.0" prefWidth="70.0" 
text="CAR" textFill="#7a6ae4">
<font>
<Font name="Century Schoolbook" size="20.0" />
</font>
</Label>
<Label layoutX="260.0" layoutY="73.0" prefHeight="30.0" prefWidth="92.0" 
text="REVIEW" textFill="#7a6ae4">
<font>
<Font name="Century Schoolbook" size="20.0" />
</font>
</Label>
<ImageView fx:id="progress" fitHeight="80.0" fitWidth="105.0" layoutX="215.0" 
layoutY="382.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true">
<image>
<Image url="@../img/source.gif" />
</image>
</ImageView>
<RadioButton layoutX="320.0" layoutY="250.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Other"
textFill="#c3b5b5">
<font>
<Font size="14.0" />
</font>
</RadioButton>
</AnchorPane>
```

Here's my SignUpController class:

```
package sample;

import javafx.animation.PauseTransition;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;
import javafx.util.Duration;

public class SignUpController {

@FXML
private AnchorPane parentPane;
@FXML
private Button login;
@FXML
private TextField name;
@FXML
private Button signUp;
@FXML
private RadioButton male;
@FXML
private ToggleGroup gender;
@FXML
private RadioButton female;
@FXML
private RadioButton other;
@FXML
private TextField location;
@FXML
private ImageView progress;
@FXML
private PasswordField password;

public void initialize() {
    progress.setVisible(false);
}

@FXML
public void signUP() {
    progress.setVisible(true);
    PauseTransition pt = new PauseTransition();
    pt.setDuration(Duration.seconds(3));
    pt.setOnFinished(e -> System.out.println("Sign Up Successful!"));
    pt.play();
}
}
```

Finally, here's the error I Got:

```
javafx.fxml.LoadException: 
/C:/Users/Owner/Desktop/JavaPrograms/GaveUp/out/production/GaveUp/sample/SignUP.fxml

at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.constructLoadException(FXMLLoader.java:2625)
at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2603)
at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2466)
at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3237)
at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3194)
at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3163)
at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3136)
at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3113)
at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:3106)
at GaveUp/sample.LoginController.signUp(LoginController.java:53)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at         
    java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at   
    java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke
         (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
at com.sun.javafx.reflect.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:76)
at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor2.invoke(Unknown Source)
at  
    java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke
    (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.reflect.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:273)
at javafx.fxml/com.sun.javafx.fxml.MethodHelper.invoke(MethodHelper.java:83)
at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1784)
at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ControllerMethodEventHandler.handle(FXMLLoader.java:1670)
at 
    javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent
    (CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
at 
    javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent
    (EventHandlerManager.java:238)
at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent
    (EventHandlerManager.java:191)
at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent
    (CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent
    (BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent
    (EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent
    (BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent
    (EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent
    (BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent
    (EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:49)
at javafx.base/javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Node.fireEvent(Node.java:8879)
at javafx.controls/javafx.scene.control.Button.fire(Button.java:200)
at javafx.controls/com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.ButtonBehavior.mouseReleased
    (ButtonBehavior.java:206)
at javafx.controls/com.sun.javafx.scene.control.inputmap.InputMap.handle(InputMap.java:274)
at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord
    .handleBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:218)
at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent       
    (CompositeEventHandler.java:80)
at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent
    (EventHandlerManager.java:238)
at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent
    (EventHandlerManager.java:191)
at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent
    (CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent
    (BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent
    (EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent
    (BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent
    (EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent
    (BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent
    (EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
at javafx.base/javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3851)
at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1200(Scene.java:3579)
at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene.processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1849)
at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2588)
at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run
    (GlassViewEventHandler.java:397)
at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run
    (GlassViewEventHandler.java:295)
at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:389)
at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$2
    (GlassViewEventHandler.java:434)
at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock
    (QuantumToolkit.java:390)
at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent
    (GlassViewEventHandler.java:433)
at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:556)
at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:942)
at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$runLoop$3(WinApplication.java:174)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:835)
    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set javafx.scene.control.TextField 
    field sample.SignUpController.location to java.net.URL
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException
    (UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:167)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException
    (UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:171)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.UnsafeObjectFieldAccessorImpl.set
    (UnsafeObjectFieldAccessorImpl.java:81)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Field.set(Field.java:780)
at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.injectFields(FXMLLoader.java:1174)
at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2579)
... 66 more
```

Comment: Please break this code down to a [mre].

Answer (score 1):

**TL;DR:** You have a `TextField` field named "location" in your `SignUpController` class. Change the field name, along with the corresponding `fx:id` attribute in the FXML file, to something else other than "location" or "resources". For example, "locationField".

---

JavaFX controllers can be configured to perform initialization after all FXML-injected fields have been injected. This used to only be possible by implementing the `Initializable` interface. That interface has a single method which accepts a `URL` argument, representing the location of the FXML file, and a `ResourceBundle` argument. But here's what [the documentation](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/14/javafx.fxml/javafx/fxml/Initializable.html) of `Initializable` has to say:

> Controller initialization interface.
>
> *NOTE* **This interface has been superseded by automatic injection of `location` and `resources` properties into the controller** *[emphasis added]*. `FXMLLoader` will now automatically call any suitably annotated no-arg `initialize()` method defined by the controller. It is recommended that the injection approach be used whenever possible.

In other words, instead of implementing the interface it is preferred to use:

```java
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;

public class Controller {

    @FXML private URL location; // if needed
    @FXML private ResourceBundle resources; // if needed

    @FXML
    private void initialize() {} // if needed
}
```

This effectively makes `location` and `resources` reserved identifiers when using FXML, despite not being clearly documented as such. And that's where your problem is coming from. Your controller has:

```java
@FXML private TextField location;
```

And the error you're getting is:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set javafx.scene.control.TextField field sample.SignUpController.location to java.net.URL
```

Because the `FXMLLoader` sees a field named "location" and annotated with `@FXML` and attempts to assign the location of the FXML file to it. The fix is to use a different identifier than "location" (or "resources") for your `TextField`, both in the controller and the FXML file.